# Will vs Would usage in sentences

Tags: will-would

1)So as promised by me , I **would** be doing it for you.

2)So as promised by me , I **will** be doing it for you.

A person said first sentence to me , when I did the work he asked. What happens if he used **will** instead of **would** ? What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

"Would", in place of "will" suggests a *hypothetical* outcome.

It may be that the person who said this to you made a mistake - even native speakers get their words mixed up sometimes in everyday speech. But if someone had taken the care to choose between 'will' and 'would', the difference would be that "I *will* be doing it" shows *certainty*, whereas "I *would* be doing it" suggests some degree of indecision.

Comment: By the way, we seldom say, "As promised by me". We prefer "As I promised," "As I said," "As I told you."